# Left Join vs Inner Join

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have lesser records for left Join when compared to inner join on the same query?

If yes, under what circumstances? Since I do understand that inner join records will appear in all types of joins unless specifically queried not to, therefore as per norm, full join, left and right join should inc inner join records.

Answer (score 0):

For simple queries, no.  For complex queries, it is possible.  In the following query, changing the inner to a left can result in adding back records suppressed by the condition on B.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B
  INNER JOIN C
    ON B.c_id = C.id
    ON A.b_id = B.id
WHERE B.status_xt IS NULL or B.status_xt <> 'foo';
```

(Note, the order of the `ON` clauses means that B is joined to C before their union is joined to A.  Then the `WHERE` is applied.  This order matters to behavior.)

Comment: ... Is this something mySQL-specific?  The RDBMS I'm on (DB2 for i) will complain if I give two `ON` clauses (I could wrap it in parenthesis, though).  Also, I'd be hesitant to use anything where the ordering of a clause like that changes behavior; it's asking for trouble when a less-knowledgeable coder comes around.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse My understanding was that it is specified in the standard.  I encountered that feature in PostgreSQL and think I also found it in MySQL.  But I have not tested extensively.